# Random permutation graph and Mahonian numbers

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $K_m$ be the number of m-cliques, $m \in N$, in a random permutation graph $G_n$ with $n$ vertices and $\pi_n$ is the corresponding permutation representation in $S_n$. Let $K_1=n$,  and $K_2$ is the number of edges in $G_n$ is the number of inversions in $\pi_n$ (denoted by $Inv(\pi_n)$).
In other words the matter of understanding is that a 1−clique is a vertex and there are n of them and the 2−clique is an edge and by construction there are $Inv(π_n)$.

I wonder if we can assosiate the such random permutation graph with Mahonian numbers from OEIS [A008302](http://oeis.org/A008302)? If yes, how to describe it by math language?

Mahonian numbers $T(n,k)$ presents the number of permutations of {1..n} with k inversions. On the other hand the permutation graph presents $Inv(π_n)$ statistic.

Comment: You've already shown that $T(n, k)$ counts permutation graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges. I understand that you want to extend this. I don't understand in what direction you want to extend it. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @Peter Taylor  Yes, could you look at Fig 1 on page 2 (Permutation glass article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.03231.pdf ) please? I want to add a reference in OEIS http://oeis.org/A008302 about the article, but not sure how to write about this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me several readings to understand exactly what the question is, but I think that the connection could be described simply as

> T(n,k) counts (labelled) permutation graphs with n vertices and k edges.

---

However, I'm not sure whether this is sufficiently different from the existing comments on [A008302](//oeis.org/A008302) to be worth adding to that OEIS entry. It's really just

> T(n,k) is the number of permutations of {1..n} with k inversions.

or

> T(n,k) = number of permutations of (1,2,...,n) having disorder equal to k.

in different words.